# I want to add items from js generated product table to cart table but I don't how to tell the system what table row am selecting

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart

I'm still trying to find a way to get the `addToCart()` function to work.

```js
fetch('server.php')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((response) => {
    let output = '';
    for (let i in response) {
      output += `<tr>
            <td>${response[i].quantity}</td>
            <td><button>${response[i].productName}</button></td>
            <td>₦${response[i].price}.00</td>
            <td><button id="go" onclick="addToCart()">+1</button></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>`;
    }
    document.querySelector('.tbody').innerHTML = output;
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));


function addToCart() {
  document.getElementById('fillUp').innerHTML += '<tr><td>123</d></tr>';
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<!-- Product Table -->
<table id="myTable">
  <thead class="tHeadRow">
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Products</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
</table>

<!-- Cart Table -->
<div class="cart">
  <h3>Checkout Cart</h3>
  <div class="cartContent">
    <table class="cartTable">
      <tbody id="fillUp"></tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-weight: bold">Total:</td>
          <td style="font-weight: bold"></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!--- I got a possible solution but when I tried it, I got Uncaught ---> 
<!--- TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'rows') --->

   

 var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'),rIndex;
var tb = tbody.rows.length;
for(var i = 0; i < tb; i++) {
    tbody.rows[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
    }
```

Comment: I got a new possible solution but when I implemented it, I got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'rows')

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a row into another table was accomplished mainly by `cloneNode()` and the original row was removed by `.remove()`. In the OP code:

```
  var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'),rIndex;
```

This makes very little sense. There is no tag with an id of `#tbody` there's a tag with a class of `.tbody` which at the very least can be accessed by `.querySelector()` that's why it's null.

The problem will run into as I see it is that you are using an inline event handler:

```
   onclick="addToCart()"
```

[Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). Use on event properties and/or event listeners, read the following after reviewing the example below:

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

[Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

[HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

```js
const allTables = document.querySelectorAll('table');
const shop = allTables[0].tBodies[0];
const cart = allTables[1].tBodies[0];

fetch('https://my.api.mockaroo.com/i_mart.json?key=3634fcf0')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((response) => {
    let output = '';
    for (let i in response) {
      output += `<tr id='R${i}'>
            <td><button name='itm' class='itm' type='button'>${response[i].item}</button></td>
            <td>₦${response[i].price.substring(1)}</td>
            <td><input name='qty' class='qty' value='${response[i].quantity}' readonly>
            <input name='def' value='${response[i].quantity}' type='hidden'>
            </td>
            <td><input name='cnt' class='cnt' value='0' readonly><button name="add" class='btn add' type='button' disabled>+1</button>
            <button name="sub"  class='btn sub' type='button' disabled>-1</button>
            </td>
            <td><input name='subT' class='subT' value='₦0.00' readonly></td>
        </tr>`;
    }
    shop.innerHTML = output;
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

const itemTo = (row, dest) => {
  const copy = row.cloneNode(true);
  row.remove();
  dest.appendChild(copy);
  const btns = copy.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  const fields = copy.querySelectorAll('input');
  if (dest === cart) {
    btns[0].disabled = false;
  } else {
    btns.forEach(btn => btn.disabled = true);
    fields[0].value = fields[1].value;
    fields[2].value = '0';
    fields[3].value = '₦0.00';
  }
};

const addToSubFrom = (row, dir) => {
  let D = dir === undefined ? 1 : dir;
  const cells = row.children;
  let add = row.querySelector('.add');
  let sub = row.querySelector('.sub');
  let prc = cells[1].textContent.substring(1);
  let qty = cells[2].firstElementChild;
  let cnt = cells[3].firstElementChild;
  let subT = cells[4].firstElementChild;

  let c = +cnt.value + D;
  if (c === 0) {
    sub.disabled = true;
  } else {
    sub.disabled = false;
  }
  let q = +qty.value - D;
  if (q === 0) {
    add.disabled = true;
  } else {
    add.disabled = false;
  }
  let p = +prc;
  let sT = ((p * 100) * c) / 100;

  cnt.value = c;
  qty.value = q;
  subT.value = '₦' + sT.toFixed(2);
};

const getTotal = array => array.map(inp => +inp.value.substring(1) * 100).reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur);

const addToCart = e => {
  const io = e.currentTarget.elements;
  const btn = e.target;

  if (btn.matches('button')) {
    let row = document.querySelector('#' + btn.closest('tr').id);
    let S;
    switch (btn.name) {
      case 'itm':
        let dest = btn.closest('tbody').className === 'shop' ? cart : shop;
        itemTo(row, dest);
        S = [...io.subT];
        io.total.value = (getTotal(S) / 100).toFixed(2);
        break;
      case 'add':
        S = [...io.subT];
        addToSubFrom(row);
        io.total.value = (getTotal(S) / 100).toFixed(2);
        break;
      case 'sub':
        S = [...io.subT];
        addToSubFrom(row, -1);
        io.total.value = (getTotal(S) / 100).toFixed(2);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
};

const UI = document.forms[0];
UI.onclick = addToCart;
```

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  font-size: 3ch;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

caption {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900
}

.h1 {
  width: 35%;
}

.h3 {
  width: 20%;
}

.h3 {
  width: 10%;
}

.h4 {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: left;
}

.h5 {
  width: 15%;
}

td:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  text-align: center;
}

tfoot th {
  text-align: right;
}

input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.15;
}

input,
output,
td:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-family: Consolas
}

button {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

output {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.qty,
.cnt,
.subT {
  width: 2ch;
  border: 0;
}

.subT {
  width: 6ch
}
```

```html
<!-- Product Table -->
<form>
  <table>
    <caption>
      iMart™ Online Wholesale
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <th class='h1'>Item</th>
      <th class='h2'>Price</th>
      <th class='h3'>Qty</th>
      <th class='h4'>Count</th>
      <th class='h5'>SubTotal</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='shop'></tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Cart Table -->

  <table>
    <caption>Checkout Cart</caption>
    <thead>
      <th class='h1'>Item</th>
      <th class='h2'>Price</th>
      <th class='h3'>Qty</th>
      <th class='h4'>Count</th>
      <th class='h5'>SubTotal</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='cart'></tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='4'>Total: ₦</th>
        <td><output id='total'></output></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
```